# Sponsored results on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, search, sponsored-tags

I was having a look at the Stack Overflow entry on [this website](http://rcs.seerinteractive.com/money/#stack-overflow) where they mention that Stack Overflow makes money through sponsored results (and ads). Is that correct? If so, does anybody know how or where these sponsored results are displayed? The two sources on the website don't provide much more information.

Comment: It makes money through ads, but the search results are clean.

Comment: I think he may be talking about _tag_ sponsors, which do appear in results (or anywhere else you see the sponsored tag).

Comment: The first link they make is just to another list with an assertion without any backup and the second link is to a nice long article that doesn't mention sponsored results.

Comment: Sponsored results is putting things in prominent places in the results list because of sponsorship and messes up your seach results from the ordering you chose.  SO doesn't do that. Sponsored links yes, sponsored results, no. The search results are clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is mentioned [here](https://stackexchange.com/about/contact):

> Ad Sales and Sponsorships
> To buy ads **or inquire about tag sponsorships**, please contact us at ads@stackexchange.com...

Tag sponsorship means having an icon besides the tag name and having "Sponsored links for this tag" on the tag info page. Good example is the [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag on Stack Overflow:

> [image]

See this for more details: [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean) and this to learn more how Stack Exchange makes money: [What is Stack Overflow's business model?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model)