# How long will Stack Overflow at least exist?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

I like this site, and it'd be a shame if all the work people have put into this place would go to waste, but usually everything dies, even on the Internet.

Are there plans to prevent that (like business plans)? And how long of a forecast do they offer?

Would the Stack Overflow contents be released to the public (in some format) to back it up, if it goes down?

Comment: There are no guarantees, but it'll probably be around for at least another 6 - 8 weeks.

Comment: @Arjan The url would pose a problem though. They can not both use the same url.

Comment: Odds are that the correct answer to this question will contain `42`.

Comment: FWIW: [Stack Exchange Creative Commons data now hosted by the Internet Archive](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/?cb=1)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The business plan is to not go out of business. :)

Seriously though, we already provide (mostly) regular data dumps of all of the content from Stack Overflow and other sites. You can find them [here](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump).

Beyond that, content and other metadata from graduated and public beta sites, including Stack Overflow, is available on our [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com). Feel free to write your own queries to grab any sort of data you'd want to back up and keep a copy ([with appropriate attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)) wherever you like.

For sites that don't make it through beta, the content snapshots taken at the time when the site was shut down are available from their corresponding proposals on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).

Comment: well that's reassuring :)

Comment: He's not kidding, I opened `BusinessPlan.doc` and it literally says that.

Comment: @AdamLear: Wasn't the data for SO itself available itself at some point?

Comment: @0xC0000022L I'm not sure. Maybe before Super User and Server Fault were created? That's a bit before my time. :)

Comment: I hear that careers.so thing brings in enough money to keep the lights on for at least a few more weeks :)

Comment: How about the software in case of a shutdown? Just want to check the boundaries of the theorically possible.

Comment: @scones No idea and no promises.

Answer (score 11):

Internet communities die if there are not enough active people anymore. This can happen for example because of:

- there is a better alternative
- the management stops listening to the community
- it is harder to find new people
- there is no need for the community anymore

Luckily none of these are anywhere near the danger zone right now. But it is always good to see those risk and their early signs.

As long as there is no better alternative, and we keep the community balanced, the only risk we have is that there is no need for us anymore. Which means humanity has stopped asking questions...

Comment: Ah, the sweet utopia!

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't worry too much about Stack Exchange disappearing any time soon. They have a [sound business model](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79448/216620), there is a strong user base, Stack Overflow alone is [currently ranked 59 on Alexa](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com), all of the sites are well maintained, and there are new proposals for new sites every day.

I'll probably curse Stack Exchange by saying this, but Stack Overflow isn't going away any time soon.