# Advertisement revenue and the consequences of AdBlock

Tags: support, advertising, statistics, business-model, revenue

For school I'm doing a research about the consequences of some ad blocking extensions.

The usage of add blocking extensions is [growing almost exponential](https://blog.pagefair.com/2015/ad-blocking-report/) and so more and more people are not seeing adds and sites gain less revenue from their advertisements because less people see/click them (this is an assumption).

While doing research I'm finding a lot of blogs writing about loss in revenue due to adblocking, but I cannot seem to find real good statistics that show this difference.

So my question here is: Because StackOverflow [uses ads as part of their business model](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model), is there revenue statistics published (recently)?

Comment: Related: [Why Stack Overflow Doesn’t Care About Ad Blockers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/02/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/?cb=1)

Comment: If you want to ask this question to a more general audience, possible helping your research, I suggest asking on an SE site related to these things. (If one exists)

Comment: You chose the worst possible target for your research. SE is one of the few sites that are probably not affected at all by adblockers, as the blog post @Yannis mentioned explains nicely.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Irony... this question is blocked by my content blocker on iOS.  Can you ping someone who can determine the reason?

Comment: @Ramhound not really, sorry. Feel free to submit a bug report if you can reproduce this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> is there revenue statistics published (recently)?

No. We don't share our financial statistics publicly.