# Add a community feedback step before implementing policy or process changes

Tags: feature-request, meta, community, policy, feedback

In a recent [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343890/336163), Teresa Dietrich announced this process for policy changes:

> We have defined a standard process for new policy or process review that includes Community Managers, employees who are long-time community members, and Moderators before being shared and put into place. Our plan is to provide new policies to the planned Moderator Council for feedback periods before they are made official. We will then share it with all Moderators through the Stack Moderators Team for advance notification. We value the deep understanding that moderators on the network have of their communities and users, and welcome honest, respectful feedback from the greater Stack Exchange Community.

One of the complaints that I have heard most frequently in the past few months is that users find out about policy changes only *after* the discussion and debate have been completed in secret, without them. The above process seems to indicate that this will continue - that moderators are the only ones who will receive advance notice of proposed changes and be allowed the opportunity to provide feedback *before* a final decision is made.

Let's add a community feedback stage. After feedback has been received from moderators, the proposed change should be posted on Meta or another suitable place for community feedback. To be clear, I'm not asking for the community to be given absolute veto power over a change, but only asking for advance notice *and an opportunity to be heard* before a final decision is made.