# Survey for Moderators who step down

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators, announcements

As [Teresa](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/704608/teresa-dietrich) shared on her announcement [here on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343890/the-company-s-commitment-to-rebuilding-the-relationship-with-you-our-community), we have finalized this survey and sent it to moderators who recently stepped down.

> We will be creating a Moderator offboarding process, including a survey and interviews with departing Moderators. Our goal is to take the time to listen to and understand why a Moderator has chosen to resign and how we can improve the site, processes, and policies. We will send this survey to the recently-resigned moderators so that their suggestions can be considered.

The survey has been sent via e-mail for all moderators who stepped down since September of 2019, excluding those who had their accounts deleted or opted out of emails from us.

However, we still want to give mods who stepped down before that, deleted their accounts and/or opted-out from email communications a chance to respond to it - since we understand some of you might still be interested in the survey. If that is your case, feel free to respond here, contact a CM or write to the [/contact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) of your site requesting the link to it, letting us know from which site you stepped down and when we will send it to you.

Comment: Will the results of survey be also posted here?

Comment: I'm not sure how much value you'll get out of the multiple choice/ratings sections of the survey, but at least there were plenty of big text fields to write in as well. The content in those is probably indistinguishable from my meta posts, and those of many other mods that resigned. A survey is still a good idea to catch the mods that didn't make public statements and to collect the information in one place, in a more digestible format for the bigwigs.

Comment: @Pandya Currently we don't have plans to release that, we've built the Survey and communicated it with the idea of privacy. Mods are invited to be as forthcoming and they wish and making it all public would break that. There is nothing preventing people from making their answers public if they choose to, but we shouldn't release the results ourselves.

Comment: @Pandya I wrote my thoughts on the survey [here](https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1246224975146749952?s=20) and why I felt it was insulting [here](https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1246785319812435976?s=20). Those tweets include some of my responses in the survey.  I would take my words with a grain of salt: I'm sure no harm was meant or intended; but it just reminded me of another impersonal attempt to get data, instead of an attempt to repair a broken relationship.