# Could the company explain how their recent actions fit in with the stated "commitment to rebuild relationship with our community"?

Tags: discussion, community, company, accountability

SE inc. has stated that they're committed to rebuilding a relationship with the community. Given this fact, I would like to ask the company to explain certain recent events. If you haven't already, please have a look at these questions:

1. [New post summary designs on site home pages and greatest hits now; everywhere else eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el) and the 4-5 top upvoted answers
2. [Please scrap the highly-problematic "how are we doing" survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415648/please-scrap-the-highly-problematic-how-are-we-doing-survey)

and comment on how SE inc.'s conduct here corresponds with the commitment to rebuild the relationship with the community.

In particular, I would like to hear a response from SE inc's Head of Product and Community, @TeresaDietrich, since she stated a little over a year ago, in her [well-received initial post here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343890/the-company-s-commitment-to-rebuilding-the-relationship-with-you-our-community) that

> my position here now means that accountability for the company’s relationship with the overall community, particularly meta, starts with me.

Specifically, and referring to aspects of that stated commitment

- Do you believe that these situations exhibit an "understanding of the community"?
- Do you believe the two actions (the posting of the survey in our name and the question list design change) are in line with "Represent[ing] our Community"?
- Do you believe that these situations reflect "improvement of feedback" and  "increase in community engagement" over the past year?

Naturally, my sense is that the answers to the above are negative. So, rather than me putting words in your mouth - please consider commenting on these two recent actions/situations in light of your previous commitment.

---

**Edit:** Four months later, and -whoosh- ... not a word from the person who had said that "accountability starts with me."

Comment: @Quasímodo and on a broader note, I dislike posts that try to hype current events out of proportion seeking to stir polemics - it's a form of populism among many other things. I'm also not much for "calling out" specific members of the community (something that's a good, sensible and well established practice) and what's more we've had more than enough posts this week promoting discussion from several angles that at least weren't addressed to anyone in particular.

Comment: @KevinB I don't know about employees, but site moderators can certainly be called out specifically (so long as it's done politely, constructively, etc). There is a culture to not call out regular users, but even that's not a rule. I would assume that any employees who are public-facing in any way can be addressed directly.

Comment: @KevinB:  In all honesty this *is* something that could surface as a general question to specifically the Head of Product and Community, or its director.  While in general it's preferred not to call people out, if it's done so in a constructive way, there's really no harm here.  (It'd look a lot worse if this question were unilaterally closed and/or deleted  without any explanation, though.)

Comment: [This is not the answer you were expecting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375808/401803), but I guess it's the best we're gonna get...

Comment: @hkotsubo Comes down to "We know better" at least for some of the points. I can hardly imagine that paying down technical debt really prohibits a layout similar to the old layout. For myself, I would say that the updates improved the situation and I got used to the new layout partly, still overall a regression, but not as worse as I thought in the beginning. Of course it would be better if it would rather be an improvement visually. I wonder what they think about it (apart from technical debt).

Comment: @Trilarion: I'd say the gaslighting is the most significant aspect of that answer.

Comment: @hkotsubo: Actually, that doesn't answer this question  (and I don't mean that it's a bad answer - it ignores the "rebuild relationship with the community" angle.

Comment: @einpoklum They "...sincerely thank you for your continued feedback" (again). Maybe that is as much of a relationship as you can get. Just saying in case no further answer ever arrives.